# MAMP always grabbing focus when quitting an app in Mavericks

Tags: macos, mamp

Upgraded from Lion to Mavericks and now when quitting any app, MAMP is always grabbing the focus instead of the previously opened app e.g. open MAMP, open Safari, open TextWrangler, quit TextWrangler, MAMP has focus instead of Safari. This was working fine in Lion. Anyone seeing similar behaviour or know how to fix it?

Comment: This seems to be non MAMP specific, as others have found the same behaviour with other apps

Comment: I've had this issue in combination with App Nap, for what it's worth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111237/quitting-an-app-makes-the-control-move-to-mamp

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue sometimes with several applications, all i do is to quit and reopen Google Chrome and everything get back to work as expected.