# Quitting an app makes the control move to MAMP

Tags: macos, applications, mamp

I've suffered a bit from this issue - when I quit `MAMP`, and then restart the app again, everything works just fine. However, when I quit all the other applications except MAMP, then the control immediately moves to MAMP (, which I opened in another window(Desktop) by the way). So for example, when I use `TextEditor` and quit it, the app is quit and the window moves to another one since MAMP is located in the window...

So the question is,

1. Why does this happen?
2. And why does this ONLY happen on MAMP? I quit other applications numerous times but this issue doesn't occur in those applications other than MAMP.
3. Finally, why does this ONLY happen when I quit MAMP once and restart it, but does NOT happen when I keep using MAMP from the time of the system login (i.e. no quit and restart since system login)

I use OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and I think this occurred also on Mountain Lion if I remember it correctly.

Thanks.

[update]

I just found [the question posted over Apple Support Community](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23533244#23533244), and OP and others there stated that they experienced the issue only after upgrading to Mavericks. And I just found that the issue also happens on Xcode, but it's only when I don't run MAMP.

Comment: I have the same question. I thought maybe App Nap had something to do with it (as I've disabled App Nap on several apps and it seems to mitigate this behavior), but I've been unable to do so with MAMP.